# how to use object global after declaring its constructor in header file in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two files :

```
// main.h
// some code ...

QSqlQuery getCardsQuery;
void readCardsFromDataBase();
void createCard();

//some code
// continue and end of main.h


//main.cpp
void MainWindow::readCardsFromDataBase()
{
    myDataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "my_sql_db");
    myDataBase.setHostName("localhost");
    myDataBase.setDatabaseName("Learn");
    myDataBase.setUserName("root");
    myDataBase.setPassword("password");
    bool ok = myDataBase.open();
    qDebug()<< ok;
    if (!ok)
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "connection Error", "cannot connect to DataBase");
    getCardsQuery("select Question, Answer, MainPosition, SecondPosition, IsMustReview\
                        from Cards", myDataBase);  // I got error in here
///error: no match for call to '(QSqlQuery) (const char [106], QSqlDatabase&)'

}

void MainWindow::createCard()
{
    getCardsQuery.next();
    card = new Card(getCardsQuery.value(0).toString(), getCardsQuery.value(1).toString());
    card->setPos(getCardsQuery.value(3).toInt(), getCardsQuery.value(4).toInt());
    card->setReviewToday(getCardsQuery.value(4).toBool());
}
```

I got error when initialize `getCardsQuery`. I want to use `getCardsQuery` global.I want to initialze it like this :

```
getCardsQuery("select Question, Answer, MainPosition, SecondPosition, IsMustReview\
                        from Cards", myDataBase);
```

how can I declare it in header file and use globally in `main.cpp` file ?

Comment: Why not to declare `getCardsQuery` in your `MainWindow` class?

Comment: I already declare it(in main.h  see above code).But it throw error :( I must to declare it with its arguments like : `QSqlQuery getCardsQuery(const char*, QSqlDataBase)` but I think it is incorrect way to do it

Comment: I already create a new global variable and assign `getCardsQuery` to it. and it works :| Is this correct ?

Comment: The question was: "Why do you need to make it global"?

Comment: because I want to use it several times in other function named `createCard()` and the only way (I think) is to global it.am I wrong ?

Comment: You could use a member variable instead of a global one.

Comment: @thuga how to declare a member variable that has two parameters in its constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can declare `getCardsQuery` as your `MainWindow` class' member variable. The code below roughly demonstrates how to do that:

in main.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
[..]
private:
    QSqlQuery *getCardsQuery;
};
```

in main.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
: getCardsQuery(0)
{}

void MainWindow::readCardsFromDataBase()
{
    [..]
    if (!getCardsQuery) {
        getCardsQuery = new QSqlQuery("select Question, Answer," \
                                      "MainPosition, SecondPosition," \
                                      "IsMustReview from Cards", myDataBase);
    }
    [..]
}

void MainWindow::createCard()
{
    if (!getCardsQuery) {
        getCardsQuery->next();
        [..] 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, But I want to initialize `getCardsQuery` in `readCardsFromDataBase()` method not in `mainWindow` constructor. is there a way to do it ?

Comment: @shotgunner, I have updated the sample code accordingly.

Comment: sorry, but it got me this error : `/home/shotgunner/projects/qt/mainwindow.cpp:11: error: '((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::getCardsQuery' cannot be used as a function`

Comment: @shotgunner, please show your code. I don't understand what you do and how.

Comment: I only change what you write in your answer other things not changed.